# Linux (POSIX) file ACLs: is it possible to set a default ACL for a single user ONLY?

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, acl

POSIX file ACLs: is it possible to grant default read access for a specific user to new files/directories within a directory, *without* setting default ACLs for user::/group::/mask::/other::?

On a directory with the following permissions:

```
drwxrwxr-x
```

Executing:

```
sudo setfacl -Rdm user:someuser:rx .
```

Results in:

```
default:user::rwx
default:user:someuser:r-x
default:group::r-x
default:mask::r-x
default:other::r-x
```

In my specific use case this time, the default ACL is to ensure a backup user can access all the contents of the directory. However, a service creates a socket in the directory in question on start, and the other default ACL entries above result in that socket not being world-writable, which it needs to be.

Is there a way to set default file permissions for a specific user without affecting default file permissions otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, as like below command

To add ACL for specific user you can try this:

```
setfacl -m u:kiosk:rw- file_name
```

To remove ACL for specific user you can try this

```
setfacl -x u:kiosk file_name
```

To remove all ACL on that specific file you can

```
setfacl -b file_name
```

To check your executable command is accurate or not you can try through `getfacl` command as like below

```
getfacl file_name
```

Comment: That is an answer that I was looking for. Thanks a lot